# Rope generate autoimport cache in background

Tags: emacs, rope

`M-x rope-generate-autoimport-cache` is necessary if I want to autoimport a freshly defined name (with `M-x rope-auto-import`), but it takes ~60 seconds for my project and happens in the foreground, so I can't use emacs while it's running.

Is there a way to generate the autoimport cache periodically in the background?